# Why is the output of the linux base64 command different than other encoders?

Tags: linux, encoding, base64

If I run the command `echo 1234 | base64`, I get back `MTIzNAo=`. If I input the same string into other encoders ([base64encode.org](http://www.base64encode.org/) for example), I get different `MTIzNA==`.

I see a similar pattern with the differences between encoders. Both outputs seem to very similar, but the last or second to last character has differences.

`echo 12345678 | base64` outputs `MTIzNDU2NzgK`, but on base64encode.org I get `MTIzNDU2Nzg=`

NodeJS's [Buffer encoder to base64](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_str_encoding) also gives the same output as base64encode.org's encoder, so I'm assuming that something isn't right with how I'm using the `base64` command in Linux.

What's the difference?

Comment: I assume you meant base64, not bash64?

Comment: @wu-lee yes, corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there's a newline:

```
alex@galene ~ $ echo -n 1234 | base64
MTIzNA==
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because echo has a newline, which gets encoded, but not when you put it into the various website or JS encoders (you're putting it into a string in JS, so no newline, or into a textbox in a website, so no newline, either). You can actually "see" the newline in the "o=" there (implies there's another character, as opposed to == which is two characters of padding).

Try "echo -n 1234" - you should get A==. The "-n" doesn't echo a newline.